Why can't I build Jetpack Compose annotated strings in co-routines?
I've got an AnnotatedString that calls on state changes to calculate its style. Basically, the colour of individual words in the string changes depending on a state change to timecode.
The string performs as expected if I place the builder in the normal Compose context. But it's a very long string and building it on the main thread introduces jank when the screen loads.
But if I move the builder to a co-routine using a LaunchedEffect, the AnnotatedString builds and displays as expected but it no longer responds to state changes and the colour no longer keeps up with the timecode.
What's going on, and what should I do to remedy it?
val audioState by viewModel.audioStateFlow.collectAsState()
val annotatedString = remember { mutableStateOf(AnnotatedString(text = "")) }


fun dynamicColor(timeCode: Long): Color {
    println(timeCode) <<==== dont see this when string is built inside LaunchedEffect  
    println(audioState.timeCode) <<===== or this
    return if (timeCode < audioState.timeCode) progressColour else plainTextColour
}

LaunchedEffect(speakerAndTranscriptsList.isNotEmpty()) {
  //if I build the string here it will display, but not respond to state change 


}

annotatedString.value = buildAnnotatedString {
    viewModel.speakerAndTranscriptsList.forEach {
        pushStyle(
            SpanStyle(
                color = speakerColour, fontSize = 15.sp
            )
        )
        appendLine(it.speaker.name)
        pop()
        it.transcripts.forEach { transcript ->
            pushStyle(
                SpanStyle(
                    color = dynamicColor(transcript.start) <<<<<<======= THIS BREAKS!,
                    fontSize = 15.sp
                )
            )
            pushStringAnnotation(
                tag = "timecode",
                annotation = transcript.start.toString()
            )
            append(transcript.content)
            pop()
        }
        appendLine()
        appendLine()
    }
}


ClickableText(
    text = annotatedString.value,
    onClick = { offset ->
      //blah blah
    }
  )
}


I've just realised, checking state in the function in the annotatedString causes the entire annotatedString to rebuild every time the state changes, which is kind of not what I was hoping for.
But it means I just need to add the state (audiostate.timecode) as a key on the launchedeffect, and it works as expected . . . except it rebuilds every 100 milliseconds!
I wonder if there is some other way to have the annotedString styled dynamically, without it rebuilding entirely on every style change??

That said, I just ran profiler over it, and it's not a huge CPU suck. I guess Compose just likes to recompose things a lot...

Changing the LaunchedEffect key as followed solved my problem.
LaunchedEffect(speakerAndTranscriptsList.isNotEmpty(),audioState.timeCode) {
 //builder goes here

}

